# Handling Spring context refresh during high load

Tags: spring-boot

We're using Spring Boot `v2.1.3.RELEASE` and while load testing we observed that Spring context is refreshing automatically. Until, this point I wasn't aware of the fact that the context can refresh when it finds a new class (or spring annotated class) and this can happen multiple times automatically.

Since the context is refreshing during high load, we immediately start to see failures as traffic is still flowing into the system. While we can create a listener to handle context refresh event, it doesn't cover handling of inflight transactions.

Is there a way to either prevent refresh altogether or perhaps queue the transactions so that atleast we see slow transactions rather than failing transactions?

**UPDATE**

This application was deployed using kubernetes on AWS. I have found that during high load, k8 controller is unable to connect to the application as connection requests for liveness and readiness checks are refused by the application. Because k8 controller is unable to perform liveness and readiness checks, it restarts the container (Not the pod). Hence we saw spring context refresh.